# Ruby CSV File Parsing, Headers won't format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, csv, header

My rb file reads:

```
require "csv"
puts "Program1 initialized."

contents = CSV.open "data.csv", headers: true
contents.each do |row|
  name = row[4]
  puts name
end
```

...but when i run it in ruby it wont load the program. it gives me the error message about the headers:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
contents = CSV.open "data.csv", headers: true
```

so I'm trying to figure out, why won't ruby let me parse this file? I've tried using other csv files I have and it won't load, and gives me an error message. I'm trying just to get the beginning of the program going! I feel like it has to do with the headers. I've updated as much as I can, mind you I'm using ruby 1.8.7. I read somewhere else that I could try to run the program in irb but it didn't seem like it needed it. so yeah... thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: The `headers: true` syntax doesn't work in 1.8.7, you'd want to say `:headers => true`. But that won't solve the whole problem because of what sammy says below.

Comment: Thanks finally got it workin. I guess I had to just update ruby :/ (noobnesss)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using this with Ruby 1.8.7, `:headers => true` won't work in this way. 
The simplest way to ignore the headers and get your data is to `shift` the first row in the data, which would be the headers:

```
require 'csv'
contents = CSV.open("data.csv", 'r')
contents.shift

contents.each do |row|
  name = row[4]
  puts name
end
```

If you do want to use the syntax with headers in ruby 1.8, you would need to use FasterCSV, something similar to this:

```
require 'fastercsv'

FasterCSV.foreach("data.csv", :headers => true) do |fcsv_obj|
puts fcsv_obj['name']
end
```

(Refer this question for further read: [Parse CSV file with header fields as attributes for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717464/ruby-parse-csv-file-with-header-fields-as-attributes-for-each-row))