# Parse CSV File, Take Input From Columns, Output to A New Column and Export to a new CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I have a CSV that has 7-8 columns of data.

For each row, I want to 
1) take the value of 2 of the columns
2) use those values in a method I have defined
3) add the output to a new column
4) delete the original 2 columns
5) export into a new CSV

I'm extremely new to Ruby and programming in general, and I can't seem to find any answers (that I can understand) on how to do this.

An example of what I have is this:

CSV Headers: Title, Day, Date, Time
Example Values: Fun in the Sun, Wed, 09/11/14, 3:00 pm

The methods I've (tried to write) that will combine date and time:

```
def convert_time (time) 
    time_array = time.split(" ")
    time_numbers = time_array[0]
    time_mod = time_array[1]
    time_numbers = time_numbers.split("")
    if time_mod == "pm" 
        time_numbers[0] = (time_numbers[0].to_i + 12).to_s
    end
    time_numbers.join("") 
end

def add_date (date, time)
    # 09/11/14 -> 20140911
    date_array = date.split("/")
    new_date = "2014" + date_array[0] + date_array[1]
    output = "TZID=AMERICA/LOS ANGELES:#{new_date}" + "t" + convert_time(time)
end
```

I want to take the values in CSV file (date and time) and add them as parameters in my add_date method to get a value which i add to the CSV in a new column

Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing a snip-it of your CSV file, I can't give you an exact answer. I can, however, use a CSV file I made that should look something like your data. You'll have to fill in the gaps wherever they are.

I've never dealt with parsing CSV files in Ruby before, so I'll step through my problem solving process and hopefully it illustrates how you can solve this type of problem in the future.

First off, here is the CSV file I'm using:

```
Title, Day, Date, Time
Fun in the Sun, Wed, 09/11/14, 3:00 pm
```

A quick Google search of `Ruby CSV` yields the documentation for Ruby's CSV parsing class: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html.

Further Googling for `Ruby csv headers` yields this stack overflow post:  [Parse CSV file with header fields as attributes for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717464/ruby-parse-csv-file-with-header-fields-as-attributes-for-each-row)

Great, now we can do this:

```
CSV.foreach('my_file.csv', :headers => true) do |csv_obj|
  # Access CSV data here
end
```

Looking at the documentation for the CSV class, we can also write data to a CSV. Finally, we can solve your problem:

```
def add_date (date, time)
  # 09/11/14 -> 20140911
  date_array = date.split("/")
  new_date = "2014" + date_array[0] + date_array[1]
  output = "TZID=AMERICA/LOS ANGELES:#{new_date}" + "t" + convert_time(time)
end

CSV.open('output_file.csv', 'wb') do |csv_out|
  CSV.foreach('input_file.csv', :headers => true) do |csv_in|
    csv_out << [csv_in['Title'], csv_in['Day'], add_date(csv_in['Date'], csv_in['Time'])]
  end
end
```

Make sense?