# Find header by name and rename with Ruby CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, header

I have a CSV and 2 file headers I want to change.

```
"h1","h2","h3","h4"
"d1","d2","d3","d4"
```

csv = CSV.read(file,headers:true)

How can I find, for example, "h3" and change it's name to "header3"?

Comment: this question may have been answered here? : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717464/parse-csv-file-with-header-fields-as-attributes-for-each-row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, and why this isn't a function in the CSV library; it can be done with File and gsub.

[How to search file text for a pattern and replace it with a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274605/ruby-search-file-text-for-a-pattern-and-replace-it-with-a-given-value)